# I got athentication error when im trying to post a request using axios api in vue.js

Tags: python, django, vue.js, axios

commerce website and this is my checkout.vue code when post request an authenticated error 401 and i don't know where the problem is some says its becuase axios and i should replace it with fetch api,any suggestion?

```
   const data={
            'first_name':this.first_name,
            'last_name':this.last_name,
            'eamil':this.eamil,
            'address':this.address,
            "zipcode":this.zipcode,
            "place":this.place,
            "phone":this.phone,
            "items":items,
            'stripe_token':token.id

        }
        await axios
        .post("/api/v1/checkout/",data)
        .then(response=>{
            this.$store.commit("clearCart")
            this.$router.push("/cart/success")
        })
        .catch(error=>{
            this.errors.push("Something went wrong. Please try again")
            console.log(error)
        })
        this.$store.commit('setIsLoading',false)
    }
```

this the django view for the checkout operation

```py
@api_view(['POST'])
@authentication_classes([authentication.TokenAuthentication])
@permission_classes([permissions.IsAuthenticated])
def checkout(request):
    serializer = OrderSerializer(data=request.data)

    if serializer.is_valid():
        stripe.api_key = settings.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY
        paid_amount = sum(item.get('quantity') * item.get('product').price for item in serializer.validated_data['items'])

        try:
            charge = stripe.Charge.create(
                amount=int(paid_amount * 100),
                currency='USD',
                description='Charge from Djackets',
                source=serializer.validated_data['stripe_token']
            )

            serializer.save(user=request.user, paid_amount=paid_amount)

            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        except Exception:
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: It has nothing to do with fetch vs. axios.  You even mention the actual problem, "authenticated error"  [401 error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/401): "_indicates that the client request has not been completed because it lacks valid authentication credentials for the requested resource._".  This is a problem with your frontend request not containing proper authorization/credentials so your backend rejects it.

Comment: the problems is i dont know why the request lacks valid authentication credentials
everything seems fine when i signup and the user showsup in my admin panel but when it comes to checkout the back-end refuse the requets,do you have any suggestions and thank you

Comment: do you have access to the backend?  you need to look there to find out what is expected from frontend requests.  otherwise, if it's a third party backend service you should hopefully find the information from the relevant documentation.

Comment: yes i have acces i built the back-end using django and i've already checked and the back-end expect data from a checkout form(first name,last name,email etc.) and everything in the code seems fine i truly dont know what causes the athentication problem

Comment: here is the Django back-end side

Comment: I'm not familiar with Django so don't think I can help you with the technical details, but you do have these decorators... `@authentication_classes([authentication.TokenAuthentication])` and `@permission_classes([permissions.IsAuthenticated])`, which seems to imply this endpoint requires requests include a token in their authorization header.

Comment: so you suuggest a token in the request i send ?

Comment: Are you familiar with Django yourself?  If you wrote this then you're the one that put these decorators on the endpoint requiring token authorization.  Obviously if you make an endpoint that requires authentication to use it, then you will need authentication to use it...

Comment: im still learning thats why i didnt know exactly what those endpoint doing that sorry ,thank for your time